# Stripe APIs and determine the card type

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-processing, card

We need to determine the type of card before we authorize an amount on Stripe for payment on a retail payment terminal.  We looked at multiple APIs, but cannot find an API where the logic is as follows:

1. Make the API call
2. Determine if the card type is Debit or Credit
3. If the card type is Debit, then charge $X
4. for all other card types, charge $X+an additional %age

We cannot find any APIs where we are able to figure out CardType on a retail terminal while the card is inserted and then have a prompt that shows the current amount on the terminal.  Currently if we use the Payment Intent APIs, once we get the card type, we need to initiate an "Auth + Capture" so we are being forced to ask the user to re-insert the card.

We have tried the Payment Intent API

Answer (score 3):

Stripe Terminal lets you [inspect card details and run business logic before processing the payment](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/collect-payment?terminal-sdk-platform=js#collect-inspect-payment-method) using `collectPaymentMethod`:

You can check [the `card_present.funding` property on the Payment Method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card_present-funding) returned by `collectPaymentMethod` to determine if the card used is a credit or debit card and [update the Payment Intent's `amount`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update#update_payment_intent-amount) as needed.